# asp.net identity lockoutEnabled is always set to true when creating a user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I have written a code that adds a user to my database using `_userManager.CreateAsync`,here is my controller code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] UserDetailsViewModel userview)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                SiteUser user = new SiteUser();
                _mapper.Map(userview, user);//properties mapped using automapper.(works fine)
                if (!userview.LockoutEnabled)
                {
                    user.ExpirationTime = DateTime.MaxValue;//some custom property I added to my class
                }
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user,userview.Password);//user.LockoutEnabled is **false** here.
                if (result.Succeeded)//user.LockoutEnabled is **true** here and also in database.
                {                        
                    return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status201Created);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);

            }
        }
```

This piece of code works fine and creates a user successfully. However, when the user is created the `LockoutEnabled` field is equal to 1 in my database. which is not what I want. I have set a breakpoint just before `CreateAsync(user,userview.Password)` and the user has it's lockout property set to false. Is there a default behavior that I need to change or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable it when configuring security settings for your application:
In my case, in `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` - take a look at marked line:

```
var identityOptions = new Action<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 3;

    // lockout setup
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 2;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;  // <<-- This line controls it   
});

services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(identityOptions);  
// Rest of identity configuration...
```

Set `options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers` to `false` and it should do the trick.

Comment: I've noticed that even if you do this, the user will still have LockoutEnabled in the db. Has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

It is set to `true` by default, you can change it `ApplicationUserManeger` (which comes with default ASP.NET Identity code)

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, long>
{
    // more code...
    
    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        // more code...

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true; // <-- change this
        
        // more code...
    }
}
```

Comment: where can i find this class so I can modify it?